# Copy Pivot Table and Paste Without Pivot Table Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple macro that copies a pivot table from one tab to another. Any idea how to modify so the pivot table is pasted as a standard table? Thanks :)

```
Sub Five_Felicia_For_MFG()
Sheets("5Felicia").Range("A1:M1000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("5Felicia for MFG").Range("A1")

Sheets("5Felicia for MFG").Columns("A:M").AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it as a PasteSpecial command using something like this, it should work:

```
Sub copy_pivot_table()
  Sheets("5Felicia").Range("A1:M1000").Copy
  Sheets("5Felicia for MFG").Range("A1:M1000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

EDIT:

If you want to turn it into a regular table (the above just gives you values on the sheet) you can do this:

```
Sub copy_pivot_table()
  Dim objTable As ListObject
  Dim srcRng As Range, dstRng As Range

  Set srcRng = Sheets("5Felicia").Range("A1:M1000")
  Set dstRng = Sheets("5Felicia for MFG").Range("A1:M1000")

  srcRng.Copy
  dstRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Set objTable = Sheets("5Felicia for MFG").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, dstRng, , xlYes)
  objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much @amorpheuses